# Payment method not displaying on front end in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.0

I have created a custom payment module using [this](http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/payment-module) link but when I update the Model class(extending Cc class instead of AbstractMethod)

`\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod to \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc)`

Payment method does not display on front end. When I check the error log, I found following error
report.CRITICAL: Broken reference: No element found with ID 'checkout.header.wrapper'.

Does one have any idea about how we can show credit card with custom payment method (Magento version is 2.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

check method "isAvailable" on your payment model , i think it is return false in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have overridden the checkout_index_index.xml in the this folder

```
app/design/frontend/YourTheme/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/base/
```

This will help